# create variables for all elements using id attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

need to create variables from all elements having `id` attribute
name of each variable should be just the value of `id` attribute
for example `<div id='btnsave'>SAVE</div>` - should be a variable named `btnsave`
here is my try - without success:

```
let els = $("*");
els.forEach(function(el){
    if(el.hasId()){
        console.log(el.attr('id'));
        window[el] = $('#' + el);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why? What is the benefit of doing that?

Comment: @VLAZ - I have a lot of divs as buttons and is simpler to write `btnsave.on('click'...` then `$('#btnsave').on('click'...`

Comment: In that case you simply need to cache the selector at the top of your script (within scope) and use it where required. This is a standard pattern to follow. Creating jQuery objects from every element in the DOM with an `id` and storing them in the `window` object is an anti-pattern, which will cause performance issues and most likely break native code which expects those references to contain DOMElement objects, not jQuery objects.

Comment: @vegas so you want to save... 6 characters? By potentially causing more problems for yourself? Feels a lot like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because you shouldn't even be writing that many even handlers (or even IDs) that 6 extra character would make your code more complex.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `id` attributes for your elements then they already have references accessible through the properties of the `window` object which match their `id` value:

```js
console.log(window.foo.textContent);
console.log(window.fizz.textContent);
```

```html
<p id="foo">bar</p>
<p id="fizz">buzz</p>
```

---

Given your comment under the question:

> I have a lot of divs as buttons and is simpler to write `btnsave.on('click'...` then `$('#btnsave').on('click'...`

In that case you simply need to cache the selector at the top of your script (within scope) and use it where required. This is a standard pattern to follow.

Creating jQuery objects from every element in the DOM with an `id` and storing them in the `window` object is an anti-pattern, which will cause performance issues and most likely break native code which expects those references to contain DOMElement objects, not jQuery objects.
*Do not do it*.

Comment: Relevant: [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278)

Comment: `window.foo.on('click', function...` - doesn't work

Comment: I'm *guessing* `$(window.foo).on('click', function...` would work

Comment: @freedomn-m - there is no much difference between `$(window.foo).on('click', function...` - and `$('#foo').on('click', ...` - I want to shorter the selector code

Comment: Correct, I was referencing `window.foo.on` not available, not recommending you actually use `$(window.foo).on`

Comment: "*and most likely break native code which expects those references to contain DOMElement objects, not jQuery objects.*" I'd like to add here - it would also break code that expects those global references to *not* be DOM elements. The ID to `window` property is resolved first and any further globals overwrite those. So, if you have some library that registers itself as `window.someLib` and there is an element with `id="someLib"` that would *destroy* the global library registration. Worse yet, it might even be some dependency of the library you use that stops working which leads to weird bugs.

Comment: so what is on the end - `$(window.btnsave).on('click', function()` instead of `btnsave.on('click', function()` - am I right?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - give me example, pls, excuse me for my confusion

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - but that's what I want in my original code - not one by one element but using `forEach` - isnt't it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - could you give me pls, your code using any kind of loop. I have a lot of elements which I want to have as a variable. In fact - all elements having `id` attribute

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I can't see how to do this without using `window` or `document` object.

Answer (score 1):

To get elements by any attribute you can use query selector.

```
let elementsWithId = {}

document.querySelectorAll('[id]').forEach(el => {
    elementsWithId[el.id] = el
})

console.log(elementsWithId)
```

You can record a jQuery element to window variable. Example:

```
window[el.id] = $(el)
```

But as people mentioned, this is a **bad practice**.